# CouchDB `_all_docs_by_seq` view is missing, what do I do?

Tags: couchdb

I am following the **Beginning CouchDB** book and in the end of Part 1 of the book, there is a command

```
$ curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/contacts/_all_docs_by_seq
```

I am expecting to get a list of all the documents, including the deleted ones, but instead I get this

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

What do I do?

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS and have CouchDB 1.0.1 installed. The `_all_docs` (with and without the parameters) is working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: It appears that `_all_docs_by_seq` was deprecated shortly after the 2009 release of that book and must have been removed entirely before the 2010 release of CouchDB 1.0.1.

There's a reference (albeit somewhat oblique) in [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-194?focusedCommentId=12743063&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-12743063) JIRA comment.  As noted there, `_all_docs_by_seq` was deprecated in favor of `_changes`.

This should give you a list of all document changes, including deleted documents using `_changes`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/contacts/_changes?include_all_docs=true
```

If this isn't what you're looking for and you can provide more details of what you're trying to accomplish I may be able to refine the answer.

See this [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Complete_HTTP_API_Reference?action=recall&rev=17) for the currently available CouchDB HTTP API.

If you're interested in a more up-to-date guide to CouchDB, see the *CouchDB Definitive Guide*.  It can be had on-line for free [here](http://guide.couchdb.org).

Comment: Well, I mentioned in my question above that the `_all_docs` does work but the `_all_docs_by_seq`

Comment: oops, sorry about that.  See revised answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much @lambmj for the effort and time you put into answering. This answers my question. :)